# Is it possible to distribute reads of an MQTT topic over multiple consumers?

Tags: mqtt

With an MQTT broker, is it possible to set up multiple consumers for a topic such that for any given message on that topic only one consumer will receive the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. In MQTT all subscribers to a particular topic receive messages published to said topic. In order to direct a message to a particular subscriber, both publisher and subscriber would have to use a particular topic different to that used by other subscribers.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is no, not with any broker that purely implements the MQTT spec.

I suppose it would be possible to write a broker that talked to the clients using MQTT and only delivered messages to a single subscriber. (It would have to deliver with QOS2 to ensure that every message was consumed)

By coincidence I was talking to a colleague about something similar to this sort of thing earlier in the week, he had found a way to do it using IBM* MQ Light and something called 'Shared Destinations'. (MQ Light uses AMPQ not MQTT)

https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-light/

- full disclosure, I work for IBM

**UPDATE:**

I've since been informed that the IBM MessageSight v1.2 appliance can actually do shared destinations using MQTT (http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/messagesight)

**UPDATE 2:**

Shared subscriptions is an optional part of the MQTT v5 spec so worth checking any v5 brokers for the option.

Answer (score 4):

Look at Shared Subscriptions https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/MQTT-234
some MQTT servers support it.

**EMQTT** (open source):

https://github.com/emqtt/emqttd/issues/639#issuecomment-247851593

**HiveMQ**:

http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-load-balancing-with-shared-subscriptions/

**IBM MessageSight**:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCGGQ_1.2.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Developing/devsharedsubscriptions.html

**VerneMQ**:

https://vernemq.com/docs/configuration/balancing.html

Answer (score 1):

Independent of the broker that you're are using, you can use *Apache Camel* to implement a route that copies all messages from *Topic A* to *Topic B*.

Or copy only specific messages that *match* an specific rule such as user, content pattern, QoS.

Other solution is using a multi-protocol broker such as *ActiveMQ* and copy specific message topics to a *Queue* (queues only can have one consumer) and consume the queue with another protocol such as *JMS* or *STOMP*.